# How to setup blender to generate 2d background(s)

Tags: rendering

Okay. Let me describe in detail what I would like to achieve.

I have created a 3d scene that I would like to render so I can use it in my point-and-click adventure game as a background.

I know how to add a camera and set it to ortho and I can set the rendering to 640w 180h but when I renderer it looks pixelated (maybe 300w 80h) which might be because it uses a wrong resolution?

Is there a tutorial explaining what I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you make sure the percentage under the resolution is at 100%?

Comment: it is 100%. Funny thing is also that blender starts to render the objects black but without me touching the lights. I then tried to move objects around to see if it was my lightning that there was something wrong with but when rendering it was the same image as before I moved. Weird.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you posted some more information like screenshots of your 'pixelated result' and blender settings

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure your render resolution slider is set to 100%,
Also, (forgive me if I'm mentioning the obvious here), but If you're rendering in Cycles, you need to set your sample-count higher, as that may be what's causing the "pixelated" look. A good starting point should be something like 500 samples. See below:

[image]

Comment: Yes. it is 100% :-)

Comment: still pixelated? how about your sample count?

Comment: A question that was totally overlooked.... What reender method are you using? Are you just going to the render mode of the 3D viewer for a quick render, or are you using the render context panel and doing a full render?

Comment: @kasperba To get a satisfactory answer please edit your question and add images of your current render setting, samples settings or other information that might help those who are trying to help you.